# discord.py can I check if a message is an embed?

Tags: python, discord.py

is there any way I can check if a message is an embed could someone help me with this?
I have already done it with `if message is Discord.Embed` but does not work

Answer (score 1):

As the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message.embeds) state , embeds of a message is a List. You should be able to check if the list is empty using something like:

```
if message.embeds:
    print("list is not empty")
else:
    print("list is empty")
```

Please post code that is minimally reproducible with what you're trying to achieve / have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't really use python but I'll try my best.

You could try calling `len(x)` on the embedded content. It returns the size of the embed, which can also be used to determine if the content is embedded in the first place.

If you haven't already, try checking out the [Python Docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#embed)

`class discord.Embed(args)` has some attributes such as `discord.Embed.Empty` which can also be used to see if the embed is empty.

I also suggest playing around with some more attributes (in the Python Docs), and see what they return on different messages, embedded or not.